# Databricks, Question about "foreachBatch" to remove duplicate records when streaming data?

Tags: duplicates, streaming, databricks, upsert

I am practicing with Databricks sample notebook published [here](https://github.com/databricks-academy/advanced-data-engineering-with-databricks):

In one of the notebooks (ADE 3.1 - Streaming Deduplication) ([URL](https://github.com/databricks-academy/advanced-data-engineering-with-databricks/blob/published/Advanced-Data-Engineering-with-Databricks/03%20-%20Promoting%20to%20Silver/ADE%203.1%20-%20Streaming%20Deduplication.py)), there is a sample code to remove duplicate records while streaming data.

I have a few questions about it, and would appreciate your help. I copy main parts of the code below:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
     
json_schema = "device_id LONG, time TIMESTAMP, heartrate DOUBLE"
     
deduped_df = (spark.readStream
              .table("bronze")
              .filter("topic = 'bpm'")
              .select(F.from_json(F.col("value").cast("string"), json_schema).alias("v"))
              .select("v.*")
              .withWatermark("time", "30 seconds")
              .dropDuplicates(["device_id", "time"]))
     
sql_query = """
     MERGE INTO heart_rate_silver a
     USING stream_updates b
     ON a.device_id=b.device_id AND a.time=b.time
     WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
    """
     
class Upsert:
  def __init__(self, sql_query, update_temp="stream_updates"):
    self.sql_query = sql_query
    self.update_temp = update_temp 
     
  def upsert_to_delta(self, microBatchDF, batch):
        microBatchDF.createOrReplaceTempView(self.update_temp)
        microBatchDF._jdf.sparkSession().sql(self.sql_query)
     
streaming_merge = Upsert(sql_query)
query = (deduped_df.writeStream
   .foreachBatch(streaming_merge.upsert_to_delta)  # run query for each batch
   .outputMode("update")
   .option("checkpointLocation", f"{DA.paths.checkpoints}/recordings")
   .trigger(availableNow=True)
   .start())
     
query.awaitTermination()
```

Q1) What is the reason to define class `Upsert` and use method `foreachBatch`?

Q2) What if I don't use `foreachBatch`?

The method `dropDuplicates(["device_id", "time"])` removes duplicates when reading records. Isn't it enough to be sure that there is no duplicate records?

Q3) The method `upsert_to_delta` of class `Upsert` has two input arguments `(microBatchDF, batch)`. But, when we call it in the following line:

```
.foreachBatch(streaming_merge.upsert_to_delta)
```

, we don't pass its arguments. How does it get the values of (microBatchDF, batch)?

Thank you for your time to read my questions.

Answer (score 2):

Q1) To achieve merge into logic while streaming you need to do it per each microbatch therefore this can be achieved when using foreachbatch API.

Q2) You use dropDuplicates with Watermark 30 seconds, if you expect that duplicates can only be created in the 30 seconds window (or any window that you will be able to precisely define) than yes, your stream will be deduplicated. (What will happen is that there will be state of the stream created)

Q3) In practise your foreach batch is (sorry for more scala like psudocode):

```
.foreachBatch{ (microBatchDF: DataFrame, batch: Long) => 
        microBatchDF.createOrReplaceTempView(self.update_temp)
        microBatchDF._jdf.sparkSession().sql(self.sql_query)
      }
```

Hope this helps a bit